# How to check if a string contains a certain Chinese word in PHP?

Tags: php

I got a string `$str = "颜色代码";`, I would like to check if this string contain `"颜色"`. I've tried using the code below, but I keep getting false return.

```
mb_strpos($str, "颜色", 0 ,"GBK");
```

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90b922307105459e2004cca643c969306e5669a2)

Comment: What? If you get **false** it doesn't contain it. **0** is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does work:

```
$str = "颜色代码";
$test = mb_strpos($str, "颜色", 0 ,"GBK");
echo $test;
```

But the problem you are facing is because the `颜色` `strpos` returns `0` which is the correct string position but your code logic might misinterpret that as `false`. To see what I mean take the `颜色` and place it at the end of the string like this:

```
$str = "代码颜色";
$test = mb_strpos($str, "颜色", 0 ,"GBK");
echo $test;
```

And the returned string position is 3 which is correct as well. A better approach to simply see if the `颜色` is in the string is to use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like this:

```
$str = "颜色代码";
$test = preg_match("/颜色/", $str);
echo $test;
```

And the output for that would be a boolean `1` which equates to `true` which I believe is what you are looking for.

Beyond the functionality working as expected, there is a clear speed benefit to using `preg_match` over `mb_strpos` [as shown here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b114940dd65b2020109e450742dc574fa9ee558c).

```
mb_strpos: 3.7908554077148E-5
preg_match: 1.1920928955078E-5
```

It’s more than 3x faster to use `preg_match` when compared to `mb_strpos`.

Comment: Regulary expression to overcome type casting? I disagree!

Comment: It confuses unwary programmer, that's all. As soon as you know about it, it does not confuse you any more.

Comment: That's very interesting, if you consider what both functions are expected to do. Maybe there is something wrong with `mb_strpos`. How many test cases did you run?

Comment: I was just wondering why is this happening, that's all. Anyway it seems that `mb_strlen` is badly optimised and regexp is really fastest solution until it's fixed. Oh, and as of selecting the answer - I have posted my first comment before I even considered answer of my own. Only when I realised that `===` is not as know as I thought I posted an answer.

Comment: And don't think that this applies to `strpos` too. `mb_strpos($str, "颜色", 0 ,"GBK"): 15.988190889 (89%)`  
`preg_match("/颜色/", $str): 1.022506952 (6%)` 
`strpos($str, "dh"): 0.934401989 (5%)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just have forgotten to check whether the value is integer:

```
if(mb_strpos($str, "颜色", 0 ,"GBK")===false)
    echo "The value does not contain \"颜色\"\n";
else
    echo "\"颜色\" is part of the string."
```

The three `=` invoke a strict type comparison. Normally, `false` equals `0`, but they are of different variable types - `bool` and `int` respectively.

In the documentation of strpos, which acts similarly, there's a big red warning:

> **Warning**
>
> This function may return Boolean **FALSE**, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to **FALSE**. Please read the section on
> [Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use the [=== operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the
> return value of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `utf8_decode`:

```
mb_strpos($str, utf8_decode("颜色"), 0 ,"GBK");
```

Comment: Still the same  var_dump(mb_strpos($str, utf8_decode("颜色"), 0 ,"UTF-8")); return boolean false